# Java newbie needing friendly helpful advise with reading in a textfield to make a button appear/change

Tags: java

Firstly, I have only just started coding in Java this evening so apologizes if I seem like a total newb and that my code is atrocious, Im very much a novice. Basically I want an image to change colour when a certain number is entered into a text field on a separate j frame. so the car appears blue when loaded and if they press 1 the car moves and changes color. My issues is I cant seem to access the text variable to manipulate it. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you x

```
public class ImageBackground extends JFrame 
{

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    JFrame F = new JFrame("CrossRoads Simulation");
    TextDemo textDemo = new TextDemo();  

    try
    {
        F.setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new       File("C:/Users/Stacy/workspace/Test/crossRoadsBackground.png")))));

}
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Image doesnt exist");
    }

    F.setResizable(false);
    F.pack();
    F.setVisible(true);


    JButton button = new JButton(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Stacy/workspace /Test/CarBlueOne.png"));
     button.setSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
     button.setLocation(130, 210);

button.setOpaque(false);
button.setContentAreaFilled(false);
button.setBorderPainted(false);


     F.add(button);
     textDemo.createAndShowGUI();

    //Make sure the new text is visible, even if there
    //was a selection in the text area.
     textDemo.textArea.setCaretPosition(textDemo.textArea.getDocument().getLength(    ));       
    }
 }
```

TextDemo.java

```
public class TextDemo extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
public JTextField textField;
public JTextArea textArea;
public final static String newline = "\n";    
JFrame F = new JFrame("CrossRoads Simulation");
ImageBackground imageBackground = new ImageBackground(); 
 public TextDemo() {    
    super(new GridBagLayout());
    textField = new JTextField(20);
    textField.addActionListener(this);    
    textArea = new JTextArea(5, 20);
    textArea.setEditable(false);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);

    //Add Components to this panel.
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    add(textField, c);

    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    c.weightx = 1.0;
    c.weighty = 1.0;
    add(scrollPane, c); 
}

protected static void createAndShowGUI() {
    //Create and set up the window.
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("TextDemo");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //Add contents to the window.
    frame.add(new TextDemo());

    //Display the window.
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);          
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

    String text = textField.getText();
    int input = Integer.parseInt(text);

if (input == 1)
{

    JButton button = new JButton(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Stacy/workspace /Test/CarRedOne.png"));
     button.setSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
     button.setLocation(170, 210);
}
textArea.append(text + newline);
textField.selectAll(); 

}     
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have any code to expose the text variable in TextDemo to other classes. You should read/modify the text from the TextField variable. It should look similar to this:

public String getText() {
   return textField.getText();
}

public void setText(String text) {
   textField.setText(text);
}

Comment: Oh right thank you, how do I go about exposing the text variable?

Comment: Edited to include getter/setter

Comment: I cant seem to get it working, I know its probably something stupid so sorry in advance but you could you show me exactly how to implement those getters and setters using my code? thank you so much x

Comment: Actually managed to fix it, my issue was it was not "repainting" the button. thank you x